# converting coordinate/reference system on IDRISI Selva

Tags: coordinate-system, terrset

i had converted my shp.coordinate/reference system from plane to UTM 48S in IDRISI Selva by change it directly at its layer properties. And after, theres message said that the changing is only for temporary and not change its origin properties.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't know the software you are using, but simply changing the CRS does not reproject coordinates from degrees to meters or between different projected CRS. You have to use other software like QGIS or GDAL ogr2ogr to do proper reprojection.

Comment: I already changed the projection outside the Idrisi, but when I imported the data into Idrisi, it automatically changed the CRS into plane (which I tend to change it to UTM 48 S). Thanks for your answer btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you import a file with shape format(.shp) from Arcmap to Idrisi, it is better to select UTM... for the Reference system at the beginning(even if the "plan" is selected by default,in SHAPEIDR window or dialog box).  This method solves the problem.